# Java: Jar through CLI - missing file

Tags: java, jar

My folder structure is bin/some/package/lotsOfClassFiles.class and I'm trying to package these into a jar without changing the working directory to the bin folder.

Here's some stuff that I've tried:

**1) Command :**
    `jar -cfm jarName.jar MANIFEST.mf -C bin some/package/*class`

**Result :** No class files in jar.

**2) Command :**
    `jar -cfm jarName.jar MANIFEST.mf -C bin bin/come/package/*.class`

**Result :** All class files except someSpecialClass.class in jar.

**3) Command :**
    `jar -cfm jarName.jar MANIFEST.mf bin/some/package/*.class`

**Result :** All class files in jar but the directory structure inside the jar is wrong.

**4) Command :**
    `jar -cfm jarName.jar MANIFEST.mf -C bin bin/some/package/*.class -C bin some/package/someSpecialClass.class`

**Result :** All class files in jar.

What could possible cause the second command to include all but one of the classes? Is there are better way that I haven't even tried yet?

Comment: Have you considered using an easier project comprehension tool like Apache maven? You'd then declare the source directories as well as dependencies then naturally have your jar on `mvn compile`

Comment: I know how to use build tools, but in this situation they're not an option. Besides, I'm curious where this weird behavior comes from.

Comment: I must admit, if the ant pattern path is correct, it is weird.